# Node.js: Getting code to run client side

Tags: node.js

I'm working on an app and I am trying to use Node.js to build it. Essentially, the idea is to get Node to launch and kill some processes. I run the server like this:

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) 
{
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');

    console.log('platform is: ');
    console.log(process.platform);

    if (queryObject.launch == "yes")
    {
        fun();
    }
}).listen(1337, '0.0.0.0');
```

In the example above, when I use the browser on the same machine that hosts the server (a Windows Machine), I get 'win32', fine. However, when I access the server from a browser on Linux VM, I still get 'win32'. This tells me that the code is still running server side. Is there any way to get it to run client side?

Comment: nodejs IS server side, that's the whole point of nodejs

Comment: You're creating a web server. Of course it only runs on the server itself. The only code from the web server that would run client side is things you return as a web page for the browser engine to execute (not Node). Even then, the **browser** is not going to have permissions to **kill processes**; that would be an absolutely enormous security risk! Any website could kill random processes on your machine! The only way to get Node to kill processes on the client side is to *launch Node on the client machine*. What is your end goal here? Your current approach is almost certainly a bad one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing here is just running code on your Node.js server.  If you want to run code on a client, you need to get the client's browser to download some JavaScript code to run in the browser (just like any other web-based JavaScript code).  However, the JavaScript security model expressly prohibits JavaScript code from doing the kind of thing you have in mind (i.e., view or kill processes).

If you have a legitimate need to remotely kill processes, you'll want to look into setting up an SSH connection from one machine to the other.  Then, you can have a process on your server connect to the client and run the appropriate shell commands to shut down the process just as though you were running the commands locally.  However, such a solution requires you have have access to the client machine.  The point of even the most basic computer security systems is to prevent exactly what you're trying to do with an arbitrary computer connecting to your server.

Comment: Thank you. I will use another solution.